# Moongse schema with array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
{ artists:
   { id: '324435',
     name: 'Gleen'
},
  albums:
   [ { album: [Object], tracks: [Object] },
     { album: [Object], tracks: [Object] },
     { album: [Object], tracks: [Object] },
     { album: [Object], tracks: [Object] },
     { album: [Object], tracks: [Object] },
     { album: [Object], tracks: [Object] },
     { album: [Object], tracks: [Object] },
     { album: [Object], tracks: [Object] } ] }
```

How do I declare schema in mongoose so that I can save into mongodb? Type : string for normal object value but how about it's an array of objects?

Answer (score 1):

Schema @zangw answered also works, but this is another way you can do.

```
var scheme = new mongoose.Scheme({
    artists : {
        id : String,
        name : String
    },
    albums : [{
        album : {/*object details*/},
        tracks : {/*object details*/}
    }]
});
```